# Regarding a single question mark in maldet scanning command

Tags: wildcards

There is this command:

```
maldet -b --scan-all /home?/?/public_?
```

It wasn't clear to me why we need the question marks, especially the single one between the two paths, So I did `man maldet` and read:

> -a, --scan-all PATH
>
> Scan all files in path (default: /home, wildcard: ?)  e.g: maldet -a /home/?/public_html

### My question:

Why do we need an extra `?` between `/home?` and `public_?`?

An alternative version of this question could be, "if the combination of `/home?` and `public_?` means, "find all instances of `public_` under `/home`, why than do we need the extra `?` between them?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to track down the source for the `scan` command that maldet eventually calls, but maldet passes the given path verbatim to that `scan` command, so my assumption is that something further along processes those `?` as wildcards itself.

The presumed goal of the wildcards in that example is to gather paths such as:

- `/home/user1/public_html`
- `/home/user2/public_ftp`

but not:

- `/home/public_html`

... in other words, to require a path element to exist between `/home` and `/public_html` or `/public_anything`.

Make sure to escape or quote those those wildcard paths to the `maldet` command, though, because if you have any paths of the form: `/home/(single-character)/public_(single-character)`, such as:

- `/home/a/public_a`

then your shell will expand to that (or any of those matching) paths, instead of passing the `?` along to the maldet wildcard code. You could mistakenly get "lucky" using those paths un-quoted, as long as no single-character paths exist, because if there are no matching paths (seen by the shell), it will pass the `?`-containing string along to the maldet command. Once any matching paths exist, the shell will expand the `?` to those paths, and maldet will no longer see (your) wildcards.